# Is it the right way for data augumentation for training a model?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I'm new to keras and deep learning. I'have tried to use data augmentation for for training my model, but not sure if i'm doing it the right way. Can anyone assure me it my approach is correct? here is my code:

```
train_path = 'Digital_Mamo/OPTIMAM'      # Relative Path
valid_path = 'Digital_Mamo/InBreast'
test_path = 'Digital_Mamo/BCDR'


valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['Benign', 'Malignant'], batch_size=9)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(224, 224), classes=['Benign', 'Malignant'], batch_size=7)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1,
       height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.15, zoom_range=0.1,
       channel_shift_range=10., horizontal_flip=True)

train_batches = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=10,
        classes=['Benign','Malignant'])


vgg16_model= load_model('Fetched_VGG.h5')

# transform the model to Sequential
model= Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)

model.summary()

# Freezing the layers (Oppose weights to be updated)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))


### Compile the model
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=28, validation_data=valid_batches, validation_steps=3, epochs=5, verbose=2)

#test
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=3, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not correct, because the way you coded this, you are applying data augmentation to the validation and test sets, and you should only apply augmentation to the training set.

You would need to create a second instance of `ImageDataGenerator` for the validation and test sets, without any augmentations set.

Comment: Is it ok to do data augmentation for test and validation?

Comment: @Annanya no, only for the training set

Comment: I've change my code ( in my main post) as you have suggested. Am I doing it in a right way now?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Can you please take a look into this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900947/5904928
I am struggling for hours, couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a correct way, but you can use `steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches)` and `validation_steps=len(val_batches)`  for easier life when you add more data though. Also you can just include `test` in `valid` since it won't help anything even you're using them separately.

## Edit:

As @Matias point out that you shouldn't use augmentation on validate. So it's not totally wrong as I said in comment but not really correct.

Comment: Isn't it the right way to calculate : steps_per_epoch=(size of dataset)/batch size ? My training sample size is 280 and the batch size is 10, so I set steps_per_epoch=28. Another question is, is it ok to to data augmentation for test and valid?

Comment: First question it is, but that value is already calculated here https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L68 . So you can use `len` to make it easier if you might change your data.

Comment: Another question, it PROBABLY ok. If your augmentation doesn't make the images change to the point of unrecognizable then it's fine, you wouldn't get good result if training set is unrecognizable anyway. But it's still questionable about, what for?